# tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified in Sublime Text3

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

When I build C++ programming in Sublime Text3, I get following lines at the beginning of any console output:

[image: Sublime Build Output]

Here are the contents of my `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH


# added by Anaconda3 5.0.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/zhuliwen/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export CLICOLOR=1  
export LSCOLORS=gxfxaxdxcxegedabagacad  

# export PS1="\[\033[38;5;10m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]:\[$(tp    ut sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;220m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
# export PS1="\[\033[38;5;10m\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]:\[$(tput     sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;220m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
export PS1="\[\033[38;5;10m\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]:\[$(tput sg    r0)\]\[\033[38;5;220m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)    \]"

alias ls='ls -G'
alias grep='grep --color'
```

How can I do to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Can you include whatever `sublime-build` you're using to perform the build as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building via an application like that, generally you don't have a real terminal used for the output (but as you see, you can run shell scripts).  What you do to avoid the message

- modify your bash profile to only execute those assignments if it is an interactive session — or if the output satisfies the shell's check for "tty", e.g.,

```
    if [ -t 0 ]
    then
        export PS1="\[\033[38;5;10m\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]:\[$(tput sg    r0)\]\[\033[38;5;220m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)    \]"
    fi
```

- alternatively, you could set `TERM` to match whatever the developer claims the output "terminal" matches.  Sometimes that works.